# Storing details in cookie

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

How can i store the user information in cookie. I have this form:

```
<form action="{{url('/Profile/details')}}"  method="POST">
{!!csrf_field()!!}  
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control"><br>
<select name="rate" class="form-control">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" class="form-control" value="Vote"> 
</form>
```

I don't really want to store these information in the database, rather want to store in Cookie, so that i can later retreive these values. i.e. `name` and `rate`. I've tried to retreive using:

```
$value = Request::cookie('name');
echo $value;
```

but it displayed:

> Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::cookie() should not be
>   called statically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store these information in [`session()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-session) or [`cookie()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#cookies) like this:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    // Store using sessions like this:
    public function index()
    {
        $inputs = request()->all();

        // Store it in session with key-pair values retrieved from the form
        session($inputs);

        // Retrieve session values by name (key - value pairs)
        session()->pull('key', 'default_value');
    }

    // Or by using cookies like this:
    public function index()
    {
        $inputs = request()->all();

        // Creates cookie instance
        $minutes = 60;
        $cookie = cookie('name', $inputs['value'], $minutes);
        return response('Hello World')->cookie($cookie);
    }
}
```

> If you would like to generate a
>   `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie` instance that can be given to
>   a response instance at a later time, you may use the global cookie
>   helper. This cookie will not be sent back to the client unless it is
>   attached to a response instance

Hope this helps!

Comment: How do i do it without any response. `Cookie(cookie('name', $request->name, 60));` doesnot seem to wotk.